# Initialize array of cstrings within a method in C using malloc()

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a simple shell program in C as an assignment. Unfortunately I've not dabbled in C, only C++ so I don't have a great understanding of how these things work.

It should hold at least 5 tokens (1 commands and 4 args).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool moreCommands = false;

    char * in = "ls -l";

    char * parsedInput[6];

    parseUserInput(in, parsedInput);

    return 0;
}

void parseUserInput(const char * input, char * userInput[]) {


    int i = 0;
    int j = 0; // Indicates current index of userInput
    userInput[j] = malloc(8); // 8 is arbitrary

    while (input[i] != '\0') {

        printf("Char %d: %c\n", i, input[i]); // Debug information

        if (input[i] == ' ') { // If space is encountered, start new token in next index of 
                               // string array
            j++;
            userInput[j] = malloc(8);
        } else {
            strlcat(userInput[j], &input[i], 1); // Concat char to end of token in input

        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The debugger clearly shows 6 items in the `parsedInput` array of type `char *`, but the local variable `userInput` (which should be the same array since it's passed by reference) has no indices in the debugger.

I don't understand what's going on.

p.s. I have tried searching for a solution but have not been able to find one.

I want the method to initialize the array `parsedInput` with strings corresponding to each "token".

Thanks!

Comment: Does changing the type to `char**` in the function fix it? Since it might not be by reference if it’s an array of pointers. Can’t remember exactly how that worked.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I originally had the type set to that, and the problem still existed. I actually changed it to what it is now in an effort to fix it haha

Comment: Also you try to concatenate characters to memory that has not been initialized, so anything can happen since there’s no null specified at the memory.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I thought using malloc initializes the string. You can see that before I enter the while loop, I initialize the first element in the array with malloc(8)

Comment: It only allocates. What that memory contains is not specified.

Comment: You don't null terminate the current string before moving onto the next one.  You don't set the memory returned by `malloc()` to a known state — you should do `userInput[j][0] = '\0';` before you try concatenating to it.  I'm not sure what `strlcat()` does when the buffer size is 1; I suspect it simply writes a null, truncating.  You don't terminate your list of pointers with a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you are attempting, but if you declare an *array of pointers* with *automatic storage duration*, then you must be sure to limit the number of tokens you allocate to number you declare to protect your array bounds. You should also consider allocating 1 additional pointer to allow you to store `NULL` as the next pointer after your last valid token to serve as a *sentinel* `NULL` marking the end of valid pointers in your array. (just as is done with `*argv[]`, and is needed by the `execv`, `execvp` and `execve` functions)

To operate on a *string-literal*, no modification of the `input` string can occur. The easiest way to handle separating words on a `' '` (space), is simply to use a pair of pointers (a start and end-pointer) where you move the end-pointer down the string until you find a space, then allocate storage for the number of characters between start and end (+1 for the *nul-terminating* character) and then just copy the characters to your newly allocated storage and nul-terminate the string.

As your loop advances your end-pointer by one so it points to the next character after the space, set your start pointer to your end pointer so it is at the beginning of the next token. Advance your array of pointer index to the next pointer and set to `NULL` for the sentinel after you copy each word.

Additionally, you need to keep a state variable, a simple `int` to use as a `1 (true)/0 (false)` flag to track if you are *in-word* reading characters, or *out* reading spaces. That allows you to skip over leading spaces, multiple included spaces between tokens, or trailing spaces after the last token. This allows you to split `"ls -l"` or `"  ls   -l  "` into the same two tokens `"ls"` and `"-l"`.

Your `parseUserInput()` can be written as:

```
#define MAXARG 6

void parseUserInput (char **userInput, const char *input)
{
    int i = 0, in = 0;                      /* index, and in/out of word flag */
    const char *p = input, *ep = p;         /* pointer and end-pointer */

    while (i < MAXARG) {                    /* loop while pointers remain */
        if (!*ep || *ep == ' ') {           /* if at nul-char or space */
            size_t len = ep - p;            /* get length of token */
            if (in && len) {                /* in-word and chars in token */
                /* allocate/validate storage for token */
                if (!(userInput[i] = malloc (len + 1))) {
                    perror ("malloc-userInput[i]");
                    break;
                }
                memcpy (userInput[i], p, len);  /* copy len chars to storage */
                userInput[i++][len] = 0;        /* nul-terminate, advance index */
                userInput[i] = NULL;        /* set next pointer NULL */
            }
            if (!*ep)                       /* if at end, break */
                break;
            in = 0;                         /* set in-word flag 0 (false) */
        }
        else {  /* normal word char */
            if (!in)                        /* if not in-word */
                p = ep;                     /* update start to end-pointer */
            in = 1;                         /* set in-word flag 1 (true) */
        }
        ep++;   /* advance to next character */
    }
}
```

(**note:** the order of the parameters are switched to make the order consistent with `strcpy`, `memcpy`, etc...)

Adding a short `main()` with your example you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXARG 6

void parseUserInput (char **userInput, const char *input)
{
    int i = 0, in = 0;                      /* index, and in/out of word flag */
    const char *p = input, *ep = p;         /* pointer and end-pointer */

    while (i < MAXARG) {                    /* loop while pointers remain */
        if (!*ep || *ep == ' ') {           /* if at nul-char or space */
            size_t len = ep - p;            /* get length of token */
            if (in && len) {                /* in-word and chars in token */
                /* allocate/validate storage for token */
                if (!(userInput[i] = malloc (len + 1))) {
                    perror ("malloc-userInput[i]");
                    break;
                }
                memcpy (userInput[i], p, len);  /* copy len chars to storage */
                userInput[i++][len] = 0;        /* nul-terminate, advance index */
                userInput[i] = NULL;        /* set next pointer NULL */
            }
            if (!*ep)                       /* if at end, break */
                break;
            in = 0;                         /* set in-word flag 0 (false) */
        }
        else {  /* normal word char */
            if (!in)                        /* if not in-word */
                p = ep;                     /* update start to end-pointer */
            in = 1;                         /* set in-word flag 1 (true) */
        }
        ep++;   /* advance to next character */
    }
}

int main (void) {

    char *in = "ls -l",
        *parsedInput[MAXARG + 1] = { NULL };    /* add +1 for sentinel NULL at end */

    parseUserInput (parsedInput, in);           /* note: parameter order change */

    for (char **p = parsedInput; *p; p++) {     /* loop over filled pointers */
        puts (*p);
        free (*p);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }
}
```

(**note:** don't forget to `free()` the storage you have allocated)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitinput
ls
-l
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I think you should reference the `execv()`, `execve()` and `execvp()` functions rather than the `l`-equivalents.  The `l`-equivalents can't be used in a general-purpose shell because the number of arguments passed to them must be known at compile time and the shell doesn't know how many arguments will be present.  You can sometimes get away with `execl()` or `execlp()` by passing extra parameters as NULL pointers, but `execle()` will be confused; it expects the environment after the first NULL.

Comment: You are most correct. I had my hurry, check the man-page hat on and typed the wrong variants. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing response! Why memcpy() and not strlcpy()?

Comment: Because there is no `'\0'` at the end-pointer. (for a straight `strcpy`) You are just *inch-worming* your way down `input` bracketing characters between your start pointer `p` and end-pointer `ep` and copying the character between them. You could use a `strncpy`, but `strlcpy` isn't standard C. For portability, everybody has `memcpy` and you have already computed the length with `ep - p`, so no need to pass to another function to recount.